# How to make raycast ignore Trigger colliders?

Tags: c#, raycasting, unity-game-engine

I have a function that checks if a game object can see another game object without anything blocking its view:

```
public bool CheckVision(GameObject target)
{
    RaycastHit2D ray = (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, target.transform.position - transform.position, m_VisionRange));
    if(ray.collider.name == target.name)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, target.transform.position - transform.position);
        return true;               
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only problem is that I don't want it to collide with colliders with the "isTrigger" flag set; I want the raycast to just ignore them. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered putting the trigger colliders on a different layer, and using a layer mask to ensure your raycast doesn't hit anything on that layer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have your raycasts ignore all trigger colliders in 5.2 go to:

Edit > Project Settings > Physics > Uncheck **"Queries Hit Triggers"**

(If you're using an older version of Unity, the check box is called "Raycasts Hit Triggers")

Actually in version 5.2.0f3 it no longer says Raycasts... It now appears as: "Queries Hit Triggers" Uncheck if you want raycasts to pass through trigger colliders.

Answer (score 14):

Layer mask operation is **not** required for this. You don't have to use layers if this is only to ignore Colliders marked as triggers. This operation is now built in with Unity 5.2 and above.

**1**.For 3D, pass [`QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore.html) to the `Physics.Raycast` function.

```
int layer = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
Physics.Raycast(cameraRay, out hit, distance, layer, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);
```

**2**.For 2D, set [`Physics2D.queriesHitTriggers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-queriesHitTriggers.html) to `false` if you don't want it to detect triggers. Set it to `true` when you want it to detect triggers once again. Make sure to set it before calling the [`Physics2D.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) function.

Don't detect triggers:

```
Physics2D.queriesHitTriggers = false;
```

Detect triggers:

```
Physics2D.queriesHitTriggers = true;
```

Your are looking for the 2D version.

---

*Note*:

I have seen reports of this not working on some certain version of Unity which is a bug but I assume it is now fixed. If not then use layers as described by [l1sten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44402141/3785314).

Comment: Thank you, some people say I should change this in the unity settings. Is it better to change it in the code or does it matter?

Comment: It really doesn't matter. By doing it from code you can enable and disable it during run-time and in a standalone build if your game requires you to do so. You can't do that from the Editor. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

Change your triggered GameObjects layer on *Ignore Raycast* or use LayerMask
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html

```
int targetLayer = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Target Layer");
public bool CheckVision(GameObject target)
{
    RaycastHit2D ray = (Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, target.transform.position - transform.position, m_VisionRange, targetLayer ));
    if(ray.collider.name == target.name)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, target.transform.position - transform.position);
        return true;               
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```